# How can I force an ANYCPU .net app to run as 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: .net, registry, processstartinfo

I have an Office Addin. It launches an app with runas=admin when it needs to set the license key in HKLM. up to Office 2007 Office is 32-bit. However Office 2010 comes in both a 32-bit or 64-bit version. That version determines if an HKLM key is in WoW or note.

Therefore I need to launch the application in the bitness that matches Office (and my AddIn). How can I do that?

Or in the alternative, how can I access both the WoW registry when running in 64-bit mode and the 64-bit (regular) registry when running in WoW?

I am on .NET 3.5.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two different exe's compiled respectively. You can't force the bitness of the exe beforehand.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted unfortunately :(

Answer (score 8):

You can modify the .exe with [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699.aspx):

```
CorFlags.exe MyAssembly.exe /32Bit+
```

Will force 32bit, and:

```
CorFlags.exe MyAssembly.exe /32Bit-
```

Will turn it off again.  There are some alternatives in [this blog post](http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/10/21/force-net-application-to-run-in-32bit-process-on-64bit-os/).